# WOWZA Streaming engine REST API not updating RTMP url

Tags: rest, wowza

I am trying to re-stream Live "RTMP" stream through wowza Streaming engine. I am using wowza REST API for this purpose. I was able to create stream file  but RTMP URI target does not get created/updated in this file. following are detailed steps followed and results obtained. 
1. to create stream file with following request

```
POST: `http://<server-ip>:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/<app-name>/streamfiles`
```

HEADERS:

```
  Accept :application/json 
     Content-Type: application/json
```

BODY

```
{
  "name": "test_stream",
  "uri": "rtmp://ingest-sgp-01.lb.nanocosmos.de:80/live/<stream-name>"
}
```

RESULT

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "",
  "data": null
}
```

When  I checked state with Stream status RTMP URL was not created in properties. details are as follows
GET:

```
`http://<server-ip>:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/<app-name>/streamfiles/test_stream/adv`

BODY
 {
      "enabled": false,
      "canRemove": true,
      "name": "uri",
      "valuhttp://<server-ip>:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/<app-name>/streamfiles/test_stream/adve": null,
      "defaultValue": null,
      "type": "String",
      "sectionName": "Common",
      "section": null,
      "documented": true
    }
```

Again I send PUT request to Server with following details.

```
http://<server-ip>:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/<app-name>/streamfiles/test_stream/adv
```

BODY

```
{
   "advancedSettings": [
{
"enabled": true,
"canRemove": true,
"name": "uri",
"value": "rtmp://ingest-sgp-01.lb.nanocosmos.de:80/live/Q0f8HNVJ1P",
"defaultValue": null,
"type": "String",
"sectionName": "Common",
"section": null,
"documented": true
},
{
"enabled": true,
"canRemove": true,
"name": "streamTimeout",
"value": "0",
"defaultValue": "12000",
"type": "Integer",
"sectionName": "Common",
"section": null,
"documented": true
},
{
"enabled": true,
"canRemove": true,
"name": "reconnectWaitTime",
"value": "0",
"defaultValue": "3000",
"type": "Integer",
"sectionName": "Common",
"section": null,
"documented": true
}
],
  "serverName": "_defaultServer_"
}
```

RESULT

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "",
  "data": null
}
```

but still in streamfile details URI is null
RESULT

```
{
      "enabled": false,
      "canRemove": true,
      "name": "uri",
      "value": null,
      "defaultValue": null,
      "type": "String",these End points were hit with. swagger-ui tool provided by wowza, POST man tool with chrome, and nodej
      "sectionName": "Common",
      "section": null,
      "documented": true
    }
```

I am clueless why this RTMP URL is not created/updated via different  requests? these REST end-points were hit with.

1. swagger-ui tool provided by wowza,
2. POST man tool with chrome,
3. nodejs Request API.

all results same.  REST service is set to no authentication in the Server.xml file of wowza server.

Answer (score 0):

To create a stream file via REST API, try the following.

```
curl -X POST --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/streamfiles/test_stream -d'
{
   "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/streamfiles",
   "streamFiles": [
      {
         "id": "connectAppName=live&appInstance=_definst_&mediaCasterType=rtp",
         "href": "http://localhohst:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/streamfiles/connectAppName=live&appInstance=_definst_&mediaCasterType=rtp"
      }
   ]
}'
```

To update an existing stream file, you will also need to use a resturi parameter in your JSON body, similar to the following:

```
curl -X PUT --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/streamfiles/test_stream/adv -d'
{
"restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/streamfiles/test_stream/adv",
"version": "1430601267443",
"advancedSettings": [
{
"enabled": true,
"canRemove": true,
"name": "uri",
"value": "rtmp://ingest-sgp-01.lb.nanocosmos.de:80/live/Q0f8HNVJ1P",
"defaultValue": null,
"type": "String",
"sectionName": "Common",
"section": null,
"documented": true
},
{
"enabled": true,
"canRemove": true,
"name": "streamTimeout",
"value": "0",
"defaultValue": "12000",
"type": "Integer",
"sectionName": "Common",
"section": null,
"documented": true
},
{
"enabled": true,
"canRemove": true,
"name": "reconnectWaitTime",
"value": "0",
"defaultValue": "3000",
"type": "Integer",
"sectionName": "Common",
"section": null,
"documented": true
}
]
}'
```